# How to find $E(X|X\leq c)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I have a random variable $X$ and I am interested in finding the following $$E[X|X\leq c]$$ where $c$ is some positive constant. Using my preliminary knowledge I can write $$E[X|X\leq c]=\int_{-\infty}^c xp_X(x|x\leq c)dx$$ I do not know how to get $p_X(x|x\leq c)$? How to get $p_X(x|x\leq c)$? Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume the set $\{ X\leq c\}$ has a positive measure, then use the definition: $$E[X\mid X\leq c]=\frac{E[X\mathbf{1}_{\{X\leq c\}}]}{P(X\leq c)}$$ and this actually holds for conditioning on arbitrary sets $B$ with positive measure.

Comment: @Shashi thank you for your comment. But How to get $p_X(x|x\leq c)$? I am trying to find $F_X(X|X\leq c)$ but I do not know how to find it either

Comment: @Shashi Is my second equation in the post wrong?

Comment: I think it is true. I'm not sure, tho, because I don't know what a density given an event is. But you might be able to do it by defining $Y=\mathbf{1}_B$ where $B=\{X\leq c\}$ in this case. Then you need to find the "density" $p_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Finally $p_X(x\mid X\leq c)=\frac{p_{X,Y}(x,1)}{p_Y(1)}$, you need to do it with care, since I have written this without thinking a lot about it

Comment: Not sure if this mistake has been pointed clearly enough (I mainly see it *propagated* below, unfortunately), but every occurrence of $$p_X(x\mid x\leqslant c)$$ is meaningless and should (if one insists on using it) be replaced by $$p_X(x\mid X\leqslant c)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$E[X|X\leq c]=\int_{-\infty}^c xp_X(x|x\leq c)dx$$
is the same as
$$E[X|X\leq c]=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^c xp_X(x)dx}{P(X\leq c)}$$
by Bayes' formula, below, for a continuous random variable $X$ and assuming $\{X\leq c\}$ is an event of positive measure,

$$\begin{align}p_X(x\mid X\leq c) & =\lim_{h\to 0}\mathsf P(X \in [x,x+h)\mid X \in (-\infty,c])/h \\ &= \lim_{h\to 0}
\frac{\mathsf P(X \in [x,x+h),X \in (-\infty,c])}{h~\mathsf P(X \in (-\infty,c])}\\ &= \lim_{h\to 0}
\frac{\mathsf P(X \in [x,\min\{x+h,c\}),x \in (-\infty,c))}{h~\mathsf P(X \in (-\infty,c])}
\\ &= \frac{p_X(x)~\mathbf 1_{x\in(-\infty ;c]}}{\mathsf P(X \in (-\infty,c])}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Please add the steps to find $p_X(x|x\leq c)$. Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you should write $x+dx$ instead of $dx$ alone. Right?

Comment: correct, will fix.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me a link where I can find examples like this. I am trying to google them but they appear to be of at least two random variables. I am interested in single random variable conditioning. Thank you

Comment: @FrankMoses The point is $p_X(x\mid X\leq c) =\dfrac{p_X(x)~\mathbf 1_{x\leq c}}{\mathsf P(X\leq c)}$ *by definition*.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thank you.

Comment: @GrahamKemp so means the Bayes formula written above is not valid here?

Comment: @GrahamKemp because as we can see there is no indicator function in the above formula

Comment: @FrankMoses It was just a little off.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thank you so much for clarifying

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think I understand the first three lines that you wrote for $$p_X(x|X\leq c)$$ (first is kind of differentiation of the CDF, second is the application of Bayes rule, Third is to take care of the possibility $x+h>c$) But I do not know how does the fourth line appears. $$\frac{p_X(x)1_{x \in(-\infty,c]}}{P(X\in (-\infty,c])}$$

Comment: Sorry to bother you but can you elaborate a bit more on the Bayes' formula?