# What is the conditional expectation of $E(X|X<0)$ where $X$ is normally distributed with mean $0$?

Tags: inequality, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

I am trying to solve another problem on conditional expectation and have boiled it down to this problem:
What is the conditional expectation of $E(X|X<0)$ where $X$ is normally distributed with mean $0$?
Any hint or suggestion how to solve this problem? I have seen on the wikipedia page that the expected value of the half normal distribution is $\frac{\sigma \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, hence my guess is that $E(X|X<0) = - \frac{\sigma \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, Am I correct with this guess?

Comment: then what is the correct answer?

Comment: @StubbornAtom: This seems wrong, I did some numerical experiments: r <- rnorm(1000,0,10); mean(r[r<0]); -sqrt(2)*10/sqrt(pi) and the values are consistent with each other.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, your answer is correct. I made an error. Hence I am deleting my comments.

Answer (score 4):

this might help you. $E[X|X<0]=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^0xp_{X}(x)dx}{\int_{-\infty}^0 p_{X}(x)dx}$ where $p_{X}(x)$ is the pdf of random variable $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you are welcome. You can also see this post which gives much detailed explanation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709982/how-to-find-exx-leq-c